# How can I make a list of show/hide sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

For my website, I'm making a list of show/hide links (java script and css), and I want each one to say something different. However, when I try that, the show/hide links after the first one don't  work. Any help? Suggestions? Thanks!

```js
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
```

```css
   .more {
      display: none;
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #36f;
      padding-left: 8px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 1-</span><span class="seccontent">site navigation</span></a>
      <div id="example" class="more">
<a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 1-</span><span class="seccontent">site navigation</span></a>
        <p>example content</p>
      </div>

<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 2-</span><span class="seccontent">products</span></a>
      <div id="example" class="more">
<a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 2-</span><span class="seccontent">products</span></a>
        <p>stuffs</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Works for me on iPad Safari

Answer (score 1):

you cant use tow elements with the same id.

Try one with "Sec1" and the 2nd with "Sec2"

```
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('Sec1');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 1-</span><span class="seccontent">site navigation</span></a>
<div id="Sec1" class="more">
    <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('Sec1');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 1-</span><span class="seccontent">site navigation</span></a>
    <p>example content</p>
</div>

<a href="#" id="A1" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('Sec2');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 2-</span><span class="seccontent">products</span></a>
<div id="Sec2" class="more">
    <a href="#" id="A2" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('Sec2');return false;"><span class="sec">Section 2-</span><span class="seccontent">products</span></a>
    <p>stuffs</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery so try the toggleClass.

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>

        div {
            display: none;
        }

          div.active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <span id="clickMe">Click</span>

    <div>Hello World</div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#clickMe').on('click', function () {
                $("div").toggleClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nyheww5e/)

Answer (score -1):

In order to have the same button and just change the text you can apply this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hide').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#par').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).text('Write me');
            $('#par').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).text("I don't want to write any message now.");
            $('#par').show();
        }
    });
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/akAn5/)

Comment: K thanks, but I want it to be so they click on the same button to show and  hide the content.

Comment: Then apply the script that I have edited on my answer. That should solve your problem I believe.